# Running a WebView Request In Another View, While Displaying a Different View?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I currently have a main view and a login view. I handle authentication in my login view (javascript injection and web scraping) and then load my main view with the right content. The problem is that I want to display a logout button on the main view. What I want it to do is send a load url request to the uiwebview in the loginview (logout url). I want to do it without displaying the loginview. Is this possible?

Thanks!!

This is what I'm doing in my LoginView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {


     if ( [[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://arandomservice.com/signin"] isEqual:[NSURL URLWithString:[WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.URL"]]] ) {

         NSLog(@"Authentication Successful");

         //Save Username
         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [defaults setObject:usernameField.text forKey:@"username"];
         [defaults synchronize];

         //Save Password
         [defaults setObject:passwordField.text forKey:@"password"];
         [defaults synchronize];

         //Close Login Screen
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
     }

     else {

         NSLog(@"Authentication Failed.");
     }


}
```

Now later on, when I want the user to logout I want them to hit a uibutton in another view that would do the following:

```
NSURL *signInUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://arandomservice.com/logout"];
    [self loadURL:nil withURL:signInUrl];
```

I want to then send this to the login view. What would be the best way of accomplishing this? (PS Keep in mind that later I will use a keychain instead of NSuserdefaults).

Answer (score 0):

Yes offcourse it is possible you can do by using NSNotification
see how

**1) Set Notification**

```
 //write this line of code at where you created `LoginView(loginview)`
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(logOut) name:@"kLogoutButtonClicked" object:nil];

 - (void)logOut:(NSNotification*)notification{

   NSURL * signInUrl = (NSURL*)[notification object];
   //now use this URL further
   //here write you javaScript and inject it to the Webview

  }
```

**2) Post Notification**

```
 //as you clicked logOut button in otherView just  write below line of code this line of code broadcast notification to each observer  and don't forget to remove this observer as doen with it in any right place like `dealloc`.

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kLogoutButtonClicked" object:herePassWhatYouwant];
```

//in your case pass URL to that object

I hope it helps to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying Kamarshad! So for step 1 would you say enter that first line in the viewDidLoad of my loginView or my webViewDidStartLoad?

Comment: @user1886754 yes you should , but let me know does `loginview` exist in memory ?

Comment: Each is a view controller. LoginViewController is a modal view. I'm confused. so The Post Notification, should go in my loginview or my main view?

Comment: `postNotification` will go inside the `mainView` from where you click on `logOut button` and `addObserver` will go to the `LoginView`